# Programming in Debug context in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, debugging, eclipse

Is there a way to program (Java), I mean, write some piece of code anywhere in IDE, to evaluate something in the current debug context when the program execution is waiting on some debug point in an Eclipse IDE?

The feature I require is very much similar to what `Google Chrome` offers for a `Javascript` developer.

In below image `$(this).text()` returns the button's text in current debug context.

[image: Chrome js debugging]

Comment: In your debug mode view, you can use the Display Window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Display window. You can write piece of code in display window and see the result immidiately.

Comment: Display Window is a perfect solution for my problem. Meanwhile what I did is, written the piece of code in the program editor beneath the breakpoint, selected the code and did Execute (CTRL + U) or Inspect (CTRL + SHIFT + I) which worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Expressions view where you can write an expression and view its result.

The material below is what I wrote in SO Documentation.

#### Evaluating expressions within a debugging session

There are several to evaluate a certain expression when debugging a Java application.

**1. Manually inspecting an expression**

When the program execution is suspended at a certain line (either due to a breakpoint or manually stepping through the debugger), you can manually evaluate an expression by selecting the expression in the code, then right-clicking and selecting **Inspect** as shown in the below screenshot. Alternatively, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> after selecting the expression.

[image]

**2. Watching an expression in the Expressions view**

If you want to continuously evaluate an expression, say because it is within in a loop, you can watch it in the Expressions view. This way its value will be displayed whenever the program is suspended at each iteration of the loop. To do this, select the desired expression, then right-click and select **Watch**. This will open the **Expressions** view and show the value of the expression (see below image). You can also manually write the expression in the view.

[image]

**3. Using the Display view to evaluate and execute statements**

The **Display** view allows you to write your own expressions, statements or any code in general that would be evaluated or executed in context with the suspended program code. This can be useful if you want to evaluate complex expressions without changing your original and restart the debugging.

To open the Display view, select **Window > Show View > Display**. Then write your expression or statements in the view, and select one of the options in the toolbar of the view, for example to execute the written statements, or display the result of evaluating them in the view as shown in the below image. The code written in the Display view can also be inspected or executed by selecting it, then right-clicking and selecting the desired action.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but Display Window was the perfect solution for my problem. I upvoted your answer.