# Java debug mode: how to get return value of function call

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

The variable view of the Eclipse Java Debug mode allows to inspect the values of variables.  What I'm frequently missing is to inspect the return value of methods: if such a return value is not stored into a variable but immediately used to call one of its methods, it is not visible in the debugger.

For example, consider `foo.getBar().equals("xxx");` where `getBar()` yields a String.  If the source of `foo` is unavailable, how can the result of `getBar()` be inspected before the call to `.equals()`?  Of course, one can change the code by introducing a local variable that holds the result. But that is too unpractical in general.

Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800

Comment: You dont need the source. Jump into the method and your value is presented in the variables view without seeing the source.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can select the expression to inspect (in this case select `foo.getBar()`), then right-click and select "Inspect", or type the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>. The side effect is that it will execute the method, so changes done in the method on, say, member fields will be applied.

See [Evaluating expressions in a debugging session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550008/programming-in-debug-context-in-eclipse-ide/26550023#26550023), transferred from SO Documentation, as a related documentation example.